# Alfresco: Why is there no Scripts Extension folder, when there is a Web Script Extension folder?

Tags: alfresco

When I learnt about web scripts, the tutorials said to leave the `Web Scripts` folder alone and instead to add my web script to the `Web Scripts Extensions` folder.  My understanding is that this is so that I do not pollute Alfresco's out-of-the-box web scripts, and upgrading will be easier.

Why is there no equivalent *extensions* folder for the `Scripts` folder?

Or is my understanding of the reason for the `Web Scripts` vs `Web Scripts Extensions` folders wrong?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I've tried to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Extension folders provide a way to override default behavior. You can put your code there if you like, but doing so makes it more difficult to override it. I will use the repository as an example. Similiar logic applies to share.

Have a look at `alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml`. It reads:

```
   <bean name="webscripts.store.repo.extension" parent="webscripts.repostore">
      <property name="store"><value>workspace://SpacesStore</value></property>
      <property name="path"><value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.dictionary.childname}/cm:extensionwebscripts</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean name="webscripts.store.repo" parent="webscripts.repostore">
      <property name="mustExist"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="store"><value>workspace://SpacesStore</value></property>
      <property name="path"><value>/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.dictionary.childname}/cm:webscripts</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="webscripts.repoclasspathstore" class="org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoClassPathStore" abstract="true" />

   <bean id="webscripts.store" parent="webscripts.repoclasspathstore">
      <property name="mustExist"><value>false</value></property>
      <property name="classPath"><value>webscripts</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="webscripts.store.alfresco" parent="webscripts.repoclasspathstore">
      <property name="mustExist"><value>false</value></property>
      <property name="classPath"><value>alfresco/webscripts</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="webscripts.store.client" parent="webscripts.repoclasspathstore">
      <property name="mustExist"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="classPath"><value>alfresco/templates/webscripts</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="webscripts.store.client.extension" parent="webscripts.classpathstore">
      <property name="classPath"><value>alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts</value></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="webscripts.searchpath" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.SearchPath">
      <property name="searchPath">
          <list>
             <ref bean="webscripts.store.repo.extension" />
             <ref bean="webscripts.store.repo" />
             <ref bean="webscripts.store.client.extension" />
             <ref bean="webscripts.store.client" />
             <ref bean="webscripts.store.alfresco" />
             <ref bean="webscripts.store" />
          </list>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

The `searchPath` property of `webscripts.searchpath` shows the search order. Search terminates as soon as it has a match. As you can see, it is no problem to put custom code in  non extension locations as long as their path is unique.

I personally only put override webscripts in extension locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder under Scripts called **Extension** and put all your script in that. Or just create different folders under Scripts for each function or project, it doesn't matter. They get picked up by Alfresco.